# Get notes text with shortcuts app

Tags: shortcuts-app

I need to create a "Choose from" script on my shortcut project. I have a list of values in the note for that purpose. How can I add this list to "Choose from" step? "Find Notes Where" gives a list of notes (criteria is set to find exact list of values). After that I tried to use Copy Item from List to clipboard and Choose from Clipboard. It gives only the header of the note. What method will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following note text:

> #### List of things
>
> The first thing
> Another thing
> One final thing

You can get the list by splitting the content of the note by new lines, then omitting the first item from the list (to avoid the heading).

[image]
[image]

You can get this shortcut at https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/3822bfae808d4abca332d643250d160e